# How to make a text generation without scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to generate texts in text("500g de aveia") I don't want to generate a scroll. Is there a widget that can do this???
The data will be brought from the firebase by an array

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqosF.png)

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BoxIngredientes extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
            itemCount: 3,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 5,
                  bottom: 5,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.supervised_user_circle, // trocar esse icon depois
                      size: 22,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 10,
                      ),
                      child: Text("500g de aveia"), 
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow!, Please, use English on your questions.

Comment: If you want to avoid scroll then you need to keep number of items in ListView low and height of parent container big enough to encapsulate them all in one go.